# Not eating dinner, benefits and detriments?

Tags: food

Google turns up conflicting result for this and that's why I though it best to ask it here. I was told by a friend that not eating dinner will help in losing weight. But then someone else said that that was not true; she said that it will make you weak because you sleep on empty stomach which might be harmful to your health in the long run. I wonder if any of these myths are true.

Answer (score 1):

Not eating dinner helps you lose weight in one way: it reduces your total daily calorie intake. But that does not mean that its a good idea.

If you are in a caloric deficit, you WILL lose weight, but the way in which you reach the deficit also matters.

What and when you eat triggers various hormonal responses, and some of them can support healthy fat loss, others can prevent it. For example, high insulin levels make it hard for your body to burn fat. The topic is vast, but going to sleep hungry isnt necessairly a good signal to the body's metabolism.

Also, if you have been working out, most of the regeneration takes place duringg sleep. You want to have enough nutrients, like proteins, for your body to best use the regeneration time.

So, to sum it up, you SHOULD eat dinner, but make a smart choice of what to eat. It should be high in protein, low in fat and sugar. Farm cheese could be a good choice, for example.

Comment: I would also add that once you go under a certain amount of calorie intake you risk losing muscle along with the fat, which isnot at all what you want. That's one of many reasons why it's important to pair healthy eating with exercise.